# I don't really understand how to interpret the following logical expressions

Tags: c

This is the code that i don't understand

thank you!!

```
Enter integers a,b,c: 1 1 1
!a || !b++ && c: False 
(a-1 || b/2) && (c*=2): True 
(a-- || --b) && (c+=2): True
a || !(b && --c): False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few concepts in `C`. First is short-circuit, for `&&` and `||`. Then post-increment or pre-increment. Last, in `C`, integers can be used for logical operations.

You can find these in most books regarding `C` programming.

For example, `!a || !b++ && c` , a is 1, !a will be 0, or false. !b++ will be evaluated as false too because b is 1 initially and !b will make it 0. That is why the final answer is false.